# Make holder.js work with Angular

Tags: javascript, image, angularjs, placeholder

When we put `<img src="holder.js/300x200">` into an `ng-app`, it doesn't work, but when we put it outside it does. What gives?

Comment: Can you make sure the script is loading properly? Perhaps see if the `Holder` object exists in the console? From the docs and from reading the code on GitHub, `<img src="holder.js/300x200">` should work...

Comment: Holder does exist in the console.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If we add this directive

```
app.directive('holderFix', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            Holder.run({ images: element[0], nocss: true });
        }
    };
});
```

Then both these elements work

```
<img data-src="holder.js/300x200" holder-fix>
<img src="holder.js/300x200" holder-fix>
```

Tested in

- Chrome Version 32.0.1700.107 m

See also:

https://github.com/imsky/holder/pull/26

Answer (score 5):

If you follow the holder.js project linked pull-request in the other answer, there's a slightly improved solution here https://github.com/imsky/holder/pull/26#issuecomment-51218083 which I will reproduce below...

In Javascript:

```
angular.module('MyModule').directive('myHolder', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$set('data-src', attrs.myHolder);
            Holder.run({images:element.get(0), nocss:true});
        }
    };
});
```

And in HTML:

```
<img my-holder="holder.js/200x300">
```

This improvement allows you to specify `my-holder` (or whatever else you choose) *in place* of `data-src` rather than specifying it as an extra attribute.

(Credit to Nick Clark and Tris Ding for this solution.)

Comment: This is the solution now [given by holder.js's official documentation](https://github.com/imsky/holder#using-with-angularjs).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-holder` directives, which is available to triggering your holder.js

it's available here [ng-holder](https://github.com/joshvillbrandt/ng-holder)

For short implementation, just include the directive and add the `ngHolder` into your app, here is the full code of directive which i get from official github.

```
(function(window, angular, undefined) {
    'use strict';
    var module = angular.module('ngHolder', []);
    module.directive('holder', [ 
        function() {
            return {
              link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                if(attrs.holder)
                  attrs.$set('data-src', attrs.holder);
                Holder.run({images:element[0]});
              }
            };
        }]);
})(window, window.angular);
```

Then in your app just add ngHolder just like this

```
var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', ['ngHolder']);
```

and in your partial template use the library like this

```
<img holder="holder.js/490x280/text:some text"/>
```

hope this help.